# How to initialize an array of objects and pass an array of strings?

Tags: java, oop, object

I am working on creating a text-based dice game for a school project. The code below is intended to work as follows:

1. Prompt the user for the number of players playing the game.
2. Create a string array and prompt the user for the player names and populate the array accordingly.
3. Create a qwixx object and pass the string array of player names to it.
4. Create an array of player objects in the qwixx constructor.
5. Loop through the array of objects and pass a player name from the String array to each object.
6. Print out all of the players names using the getName() method.

The error I am currently encountering is in the play() method stating that both "players" and "Players" cannot be resolved to a variable. Any help with this is appreciated, new to OOP languages.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

    public class driver {

        public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner input_scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Please enter the number of players (2-5): ");
        numPlayers = input_scanner.nextInt();
        String players[] = new String[numPlayers];
        for (int x = 0; x < numPlayers; x++) {
            System.out.print("Please enter the name of Player" + (x+1) + ": ");
            players[x] = input_scanner.next();
        }
        qwixx game = new qwixx(players);
        game.play();

        input_scanner.close();

        }

    }
```

---

```
public class qwixx {

    public qwixx(String[] players) {
        player[] Players = new player[players.length];
        for (int x = 0; x < players.length; x++) {
            Players[x] = new player(players[x]);
        }
    }

    public void play() {
        for (int i = 0; i < players.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(Players[i].getName());
        }
    }

}
```

---

```
public class player {

    public player(String playerName) {
        name = playerName;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

}
```

Comment: well, there is no `players` object in your qwixx class..

Comment: `player[] Players`: your conventions are flipped, by the way.

Comment: @austinwernli the "players" (lower case p) is the String array holding the player names.

Comment: i see that in some methods. However, you need to research on variable scope, as play() doesn't have access to a `players` variable anywhere

Comment: @JacobG. meaning it should say "Players player[] ..." in the qwixx constructor?

Comment: @S.Miller No, the class name should use PascalCase and the variable name should be camelCase.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of problems with your code. But the most significant one is how in every class other than the one with main, you really have not declared any variable that belongs to the class. Do not introduce the class variables inside the constructors. Declare them outside the constructor so they can be global variables. Try:

```
public class qwixx {

    player[] Players;     //declared before using it in any methods / constructor

    public qwixx(String[] players) {
        Players = new player[players.length];    //value initialized inside the constructor
        for (int x = 0; x < players.length; x++) {
            Players[x] = new player(players[x]);
        }
    }

    public void play() {
        for (int i = 0; i < Players.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(Players[i].getName());
        }
    }
}
```

Similarly, try doing the same in your player class:

```
public class player {

    String name;

    public player(String playerName) {
        name = playerName;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

}
```

And on your main, you forgot to declare numPlayers as int. Do that too.

```
int numPlayers = input_scanner.nextInt
```

Answer (score 0):

First , You have instantiated much of your data inside the main method causing your operating code to be static!
Second the following line is not declared global "but requires using **static**" so can only be seen inside the static main method.

```
String players[] = new String[numPlayers];
```

"public class qwixx" to use in the main method should be "public static class qwixx"
The following is a "new instance" not static

```
qwixx game = new qwixx(players);
```

but the problem to call it then becomes as below, because a static class is not declared new, it is simply called with a method that requires using

qwixx.play();

More than that any class name is better written by its convention of starting with an UPPER case letter to both assist reading the code and the compiler to not trip over. e.g. "public static class Qwixx"

"Remove the static contexts" OR work completely within them , one or the other ONLY.